# Why 99.998474% instead of 100%?

Tags: graphics, export, svg-format

I want to export a red square to the [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file

```
Export["red_square.svg", Graphics[{Red, RegularPolygon[4]}]]
```

I noticed that in the exported SVG file, the color is written as **rgb(99.998474%,0%,0%)** instead of **rgb(100%,0%,0%)**. Why is that?

You can output the content of SVG directly in Mathematica through the following code：

```
ExportString[Graphics[{Red, RegularPolygon[4]}], "SVG"]
```

The output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="360pt" height="359pt" viewBox="0 0 360 359" version="1.1">
<g id="surface48">
<path style="fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(99.998474%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(99.998474%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3.239307;" d="M 351.820313 351.53125 L 351.820313 6.894531 L 7.179688 6.894531 L 7.179688 351.53125 Z M 351.820313 351.53125 "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Update:**

After the reminder from @Julien Kluge, I did an experiment and found that when the R component is first represented in machine number, and then scaled by $(2^{16}-1)/2^{16}$, and finally rounded to the nearest multiple of $1/2^{16}$.

It is expressed in code as follows:

```
r$new = Round[1.0 r (2^16 - 1)/2^16, 2^-16];
```

Comment: I'd argue that's 100%. Mathematica likely passes the values to `RGBColor` through `N` and some other floating point fudgery and therefore loses a tiny bit of decimal accuracy or something

Comment: @b3m2a1 That looks really weird, and can't be just due to numerical accuracy ... 1.0 is an exactly representable number, I don't see how it could get corrupted, and why there would be any computations on it in this case. Maybe colour correction?

Comment: Notice that  `Ceiling[1/(1 - 0.999984741) ]== 2^16`. So yearh, probably some floating point stuff going on. This also means, that you'd need a monitor with at least 16bit color resolution per channel which does rule out all usually available monitors.

Comment: A better hint: `(2^16 - 1)/(2^16) == 0.9999847412109375`. Now looks like an off by one error while normalizing color channels?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why. You can add it to *other people's* questions when the issue was confirmed to be a bug by the community.

Comment: If you plot the change from the svg against the real value, you get multiple overlaid sawtooth like waves. Does not look pretty and is sadly not as easy as just (x-1)/x. I can't say what happens. However, i can confirm that the max error is about ~(- 2^-16).

Comment: Seems like a bug. Everyone knows that to convert the range 0--65535 (16 bit) or 0--255 (8 bit) to a real 0.--1. range, you divide by 65535 (resp. 255), not 65536 etc. Did you report it to WRI, by chance? The bug is still present.