# Avoid rounding in svg exported colors

Tags: graphics, export, svg-format

The code

```
ExportString[Graphics@{Red,Rectangle[]},"SVG"]
```

yields

```
<?xml ... stroke:rgb(99.998474%,0%,0%); ... </svg>
```

This is different from the behavior in the documentation, which produces `rgb(100%,0%,0%)`.  Evidently, there are some system or system-dependent calls going on.  What system-dependent things are being invoked?  I'm on a Mac in 12.1; is there a way to make it process colors such that `Red` or `RGBColor[1,0,0]` produces `100%` instead of editing the XML tags in the result?

---

Using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``, in the package context `` System`ConvertersDump ``, I think the calls go like

```
ExportSVG,
ExportVectorFormat,
createVectorExportPacketExpr
```

which might simply do `Evaluate@*NotebookGet`, or maybe `FrontEndObject@*Evaluate@*NotebookGet`, or it might make a Notebook of `Cell@*BoxData@*MakeBoxes[...,"OutputForm"]`.

I did a `TracePrint` but it was way too huge to follow, and the first place that "99.998474" showed up was near the end of evaluation; I don't know exactly what took place.

Comment: Isn't this somehow linked to shortcomings in the binary representation of decimals perhaps? I noted that, if you replace Red with RGBColor and then enter values that are exact powers of 2, they re reproduced faithfully in the SVG output.

Comment: That is a bug.  Feel free to report it.

Comment: Duplicate https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235192/82985, also does not happen on Windows in 13.2.1